# JQuery - Input tag change visibility attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a very simple input tag:

```
<input id="DAhour" type="number" style="width:50px; font-size: xx-small; visibility:hidden">
```

which at first has to be not visible. Then if I change a combobox to the correct index it should become visible. I managed to get the combobox and the selected item correctly but I cannot make the input tag visible. I tried with:

```
$("#DAhour").css("visibility", "visible");
```

but it doesn't work because if I check the visibility with

```
$("#DAhour").is(":visible")
```

it stays always equal to false. Then, when the combobox changes again I should be able to make it not visible again, si I tried again with

```
$("#DAhour").css("visibility", "hidden");
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because when you use [visibilty rule](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/visibility), even though the element is not visible it consumes space in *DOM*. So, jQuery's [visible selector](http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/) will consider it as visible.

> Elements are considered visible if they consume space in the document. Visible elements have a width or height that is greater than zero.
>
> Elements with `visibility: hidden` or `opacity: 0` are considered visible,
>   since they still consume space in the layout.

If you want to really hide the element use the [display](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/display) rule, ie `display: none` or the short hand method [.hide()](http://api.jquery.com/hide/)/[show()](http://api.jquery.com/show/)

Comment: If he wants to have that space consumed though he could also use the [.attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) method to change the visibility.

Comment: If I do "display: none" it doesn't even hide the input tag. Instead with attr("visibility","visible") it doesn't make it visible..

Answer (score 0):

try using `$("#DAhour").show()` and  `$("#DAhour").hide()` methods

Answer (score 0):

Try to check the visibility with:

```
if($("#DAhour").css("visibility")!== "hidden")
```

And change visibility with

```
$("#DAhour").css("visibility","hidden");

$("#DAhour").css("visibility","visible");
```